# Take coefficients of the variable from a Matrix

Tags: matrix, coefficients

I have a question how can I take coefficients of the variable from a matrix? for example;
I have a matrix such as:
`A={{2a,3b,4c},{4d},{1a,1e}}` variable is {a,b,c,d,e}

Now I would like to take all coefficients from that matrix to make a new matrix.
`Acoef={{2,3,4,0,0},{{0,0,0,0,4},{1,0,0,0,1}}`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Total[D[A, {{a, b, c, d, e}}], {2}]
```

> ```
> {{2, 3, 4, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 4, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1}}
> ```

Also

```
Total[Transpose[Coefficient[A, #] & /@ {a, b, c, d, e}], {3}]
```

> ```
> {{2, 3, 4, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 4, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1}}
> ```

and

```
Transpose@Total[Coefficient[A, #] & /@ {a, b, c, d, e}, {3}]
```

> ```
> {{2, 3, 4, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 4, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1}}
> ```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

Another way.

```
A = {{2 a, 3 b, 4 c}, {4 d}, {a, e}};
(* Variables[A]=={a,b,c,d,e} *)
A /. Thread[{a, b, c, d, e} -> IdentityMatrix[5]]
% // Map[Total]
```

> `{{{2, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 3, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 4, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0, 4,  0}}, {{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 1}}}`

> `{{2, 3, 4, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 4, 0}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1}}`

Comment: Thank you so much!